# Black Image after sum frames with loop in EBImage

Tags: r, loops, image-processing

I'm using R statistic software with EBImage package for image processing analysis. 
I want an image with one frame containing the sum of several frames of the image. It's called "image projection". After playing manually, I obtain de desired behaviour, but when I want to do it with a loop, I obtain a black image. This is a reproducible example:

```
library("EBImage")

# Load Nuclei System Image
nuc <- readImage(system.file("images", "nuclei.tif", package="EBImage"))

# Split Nuclei Image by Frame
nuc1 <- nuc[,,1]
nuc2 <- nuc[,,2]
nuc3 <- nuc[,,3]
nuc4 <- nuc[,,4]

# Sum of Splited Frames to Single Frame

## Method 1 manual:
nucProjection <- nuc1 + nuc2 + nuc3 + nuc4
display(nucProjection)

## Method 2 auto:
z <- matrix(data = NA , nrow = dim(nuc)[1], ncol = dim(nuc)[2])
for (i in 1:numberOfFrames(nuc)){
 z <- z + nuc[,,i]
}
display(z)
```

Comment: Is this a programming language or a pseudo-code?

Comment: Sorry, I've added at the introduction, that I'm using R software and programming language to image analysis with EBImage package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make your example work you need to initialize your results matrix `z` with `0`'s rather than `NA`'s. A cleaner and faster approach than a for loop is to use `Reduce` on a list of frames.

```
Reduce("+", getFrames(nuc))
```

It has the added advantage of returning an object of class `Image` rather than a plain matrix.

Comment: Perfect, using a matrix containing only zeros is functional now. Very interesting approach with "reduce" function. Thanks a lot